# related to using Go to Definition and Peek Definition commands in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am following this tutorial on [using vscode for developing Flask](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask). For the `Go to Definition and Peek Definition commands`  I tried exactly the same way as what tutorial says on the same code, but after right click `Flask`, I got `no definition found for Flask`. What's the possible reason?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the python plugin installed and where is flask installed, i.e. virtualenv, global python, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered the same problem when my Python extension was disabled.

Since "`Go to Definition`" is supported by the corresponding language service extension, it is recommended that you check that the current [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) is available (`enable`) and confirm that the selected [python interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) is also available. In addition, please try to reload VSCode.